# Can we attach a script element tag to document object before DOM gets loaded? using javascript

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

> I tried it by using DOMNodeInserted but i didnt got the proper solution.
>   I want to attach my own script through addon-sdk before DOm gets ready. I have got contentscriptwhen option which provide this facility using its property "start". but; its not working as it unable to make changes in dom before it gets loaded

Comment: I want to attach my own script through addon-sdk before DOm gets ready. I have got contentscriptwhen option which provide this facility using its property "start". but; its not working as it unable to make changes in dom before it gets loaded

Answer (score 0):

im sure you can do this using the nsITraceableChannel

http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=2800667&sid=77eeb915eef4615cb9f00ae144fbfa88

but i couldnt figure it out myself but im right there im sure